# Python - Count number of records occurring between two dates by matching/comparing variables from multiple data frames

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop, count

I have two data frames: one containing social media (SM) posts the other containing time stamped responses for survey completion and time for 60 days prior to survey completion (inaccurate for the example data frame's sake, don't think it would affect the methods - calculated in by `-timedelta(days=60)` using `pd.datetime`).

`social_media`:

| post | postedTime | FIPS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'aaa' | 2019-02-09 20:28:26 | 01010 |
| 'bbb' | 2019-01-11 14:11:30 | 01010 |
| 'ccc' | 2017-11-23 09:10:11 | 99999 |

`survey`:

| competionTime | 60daysprior | FIPS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-08 11:28:26 | 2018-12-09 20:28:26 | 01010 |
| 2019-01-04 07:30:21 | 2018-11-11 14:11:30 | 01010 |
| 2017-07-14 07:30:21 | 2017-09-23 09:10:11 | 88888 |
| 2019-06-21 11:43:17 | 2019-04-23 09:10:11 | 77777 |

Each row contains a respondent's county FIPS code, and the time stamp for their survey response. Each FIPS may be associated with one or multiple survey respondents. Data was deidentified, so there is no respondent ID, only FIPS and the time stamp. So, I assume there will be double-counting if a county has more than one respondent completing the survey in the same time-frame - this is not a big concern.

My goal is to count the number of SM posts created within the past 60 days of each survey completion date per each respondent's survey completion time. I have the following code which seems to work, but takes a very long time because the datasets are very large.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import itertools

full_count = []

for i, surveyrow in survey.iterrows():
    count = 0
    for j, SMrow in social_media.iterrows():
        if surveyrow['FIPS'] == SMrow['FIPS']:
            if surveyrow['completionTime']>=SMrow['postedTime']:
                if surveyrow['60daysprior']<=SMrow['postedTime']:
                    count+=1
                else:
                    count+=0
            else:
                count+=0
        else:
            count+=0
    full_count.append(str(count))

survey['count'] = full_count
```

What can I do to optimize this code? I am using Python 3 and `pandas`.  Thank you!!

**Update**:  This code improves the speed, but still takes a great deal of time:

```
survey_fips = survey['FIPS']
social_media_fips = social_media['FIPS']
survey_tm_finish = survey['completionTime']
social_media_postedTime = social_media['postedTime']
survey_tm_finish_minus60 = survey['60daysprior']

full_count = []


for i, j, k in zip(survey_fips, survey_tm_finish, survey_tm_finish_minus60):
    count = 0
    for a, b in zip(social_media_fips, social_media_postedTime):
        if i == a:
            if j>=b:
                if k<=b:
                    count+=1
                else:
                    count
            else:
                count
        else:
            count
    full_count.append(str(count))
```

Comment: I think you can use `pd.merge_asof` with the `by` parameter, `tolerance`, and `direction`.

Comment: Thanks @scott-boston. Having trouble implementing this. Would I include all variables looped through in `by` parameter? I'm looking to count occurrences, so would `pd.merge_asof` help with that? Unsure from the documentation and examples I've found.

Comment: Merge two dataframes and use groupby to count records.